# What is the `numSlashingSpans` meaning at `staking::withdrawUnbonded`?

Tags: staking

What is the `numSlashingSpans` meaning at `staking::withdrawUnbonded`?

Comment: See https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/how-to-determine-value-for-param-num-slashing-spans-for-a-withdrawunbonded-tx/5266#5266

Answer (score 0):

We need to benchmark the weight this extrinsic will cost.

And it doesn't know how many `SlashingSpans` exist before the execution.

So, you give a num to calculate the weight.

Answer (score -1):

Wether or not i can understand these:

If i not a nomidator and unbound a little money not the all money ,the 'numSlashingSpans' should be 0 it will be send successful;

If i not a nomidator and unbound the all money ,the 'numSlashingSpans' should be 0 ,it will be send successful;

If i am a nomidator and unbound a little money not the all money ,the 'numSlashingSpans' should be calculted ,it will be send successfu;

If i am a nomidator and unbound  the all money ,what is the 'numSlashingSpans' should be calculted it will be send successful;